# Abrir nueva ventana al regresar información de AJAX

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

Estoy intentado enviar información por AJAX a un PHP y que cuando regrese la respuesta me abra en otra pestaña un otro PHP que procesará la información regresada.

Tengo este código

```
function printAdmLetter()
{
    if($("#adm_nomina").val()==""||$("#case_desc").val()==""||$("#boss_actions").val()==""||$('select[name=cause]').val()==null)
    {
        swal("¡Olvidaste algo!", "La información no está completa.", "error");
        return false;
    }

    else
    {
        adm_nomina = document.getElementById("adm_nomina").value;
        auth = document.getElementById("auth").value;
        cause = $('select[name=cause]').val();
        case_desc = document.getElementById("case_desc").value;
        boss_actions = document.getElementById("boss_actions").value;
        $.ajax(
        {

            url:"./phpLibraries/admLetter.php",
            method:"POST",
            data:{adm_nomina:adm_nomina,
                        auth:auth,
                        cause:cause,
                      case_desc:case_desc,
                    boss_actions:boss_actions},
            success:function(data)
            {
                if(data=='X')
                {
                    swal("¡Error!","No se pudo ingresar la información, intentalo nuevamente.","error");
                }

                else
                {
                        window.open('phpLibraries/printAdmLetter.php?id='+data);
                }
            }
     });
    }
}
```

El problema es que no hace nada, no abre la pestaña.
Hice una prueba con:

```
window.location.href='phpLibraries/printAdmLetter.php?id='+data;
```

y de esa manera si funciona.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Es un comportamiento que la mayoría de navegadores adoptan. La instrucción `window#open` será bloqueada si no es resultado de alguna interacción directa con el usuario (por ejemplo algún evento `click`). Un código que es ejecutado por un suceso asíncrono, como un callback, no cataloga como interacción directa con el usuario, deteniendo así la ejecución de `window#open`.

Comment: Clara y concisa la respuesta. Gracias, era por que Chrome estaba bloqueando Pop Up's.

Answer (score 0):

No es muy elegante pero podrian crear un link con el href vacio y con jquery pasarle la direccion:

```
<a id="link" href="">Link</a>
```

Con Jquery llenas el atributo y despues simulas un click

```
$("#link").attr('href','phpLibraries/printAdmLetter.php?id='+data);
$("#link").click();
```

No es muy elegante, como ya dije, pero podria funcionar.